# SQL: How to speedup multi join query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

Table `registrations`:

```
event_time         | name |
---------------------------
2014-07-16 11:40     Bob1
2014-07-16 10:00     Bob2
2014-07-16 09:20     Bob3
2014-07-15 11:20     Bob4
2014-07-15 10:20     Bob5
2014-07-15 09:00     Bob6
```

Table `session_log`:

```
event_time         | name | games_played | level_at_end |
---------------------------------------------------------
2014-07-16 11:40     Bob1             12               2
2014-07-16 10:00     Bob2              0               0
2014-07-16 09:20     Bob3            146               9
2014-07-15 11:20     Bob4             11               2
2014-07-15 10:20     Bob5              0               0
2014-07-15 09:00     Bob6              1               0
```

Every time user login..play..logout I write a record into `session_log`. So it might be many entries for one user every day.

It is possible that user registers but do not login.

Levels in my system starts from 0.

I need to build a report like this:

```
day        | registrations | logged_in | played_users | lvl1 | lvl2 | lvl3 | lvl4 | lvl5 | lvl10
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-07-29              23          21             14     14     10      9      4      2     0
2014-07-28              18          17             15     14     11      9      3      1     1
```

Where:

- `day` - day of report aggregation
- `registrations` - number of registration for the given day
- `logged_in` - number of users that logged in within 24 hours after registration
- `played_users` - number of users that played within 24 hours after registration
- `lvl1` - number of users that reached level 1 within 24 hours after registration
- `lvl2` - number of users that reached level 2 within 24 hours after registration
- `lvl3` - number of users that reached level 3 within 24 hours after registration
- `lvl4` - number of users that reached level 4 within 24 hours after registration
- `lvl5` - number of users that reached level 5 within 24 hours after registration
- `lvl10` - number of users that reached level 10 within 24 hours after registration

So, I wrote a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
  date(r.event_time)      AS day,
  count(DISTINCT r.name)  AS registrations,
  count(DISTINCT s1.name) AS logged_in,
  count(DISTINCT s2.name) AS played_users,
  count(DISTINCT sl_1.name) AS lvl1,
  count(DISTINCT sl_2.name) AS lvl2,
  count(DISTINCT sl_3.name) AS lvl3,
  count(DISTINCT sl_4.name) AS lvl4,
  count(DISTINCT sl_5.name) AS lvl5,
  count(DISTINCT sl_10.name) AS lvl10
FROM registrations AS r
  LEFT JOIN session_log AS s1
    ON r.name = s1.name
       AND s1.event_time >= r.event_time
       AND s1.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days')
  LEFT JOIN session_log as s2
    ON r.name = s2.name
    AND s2.event_time >= r.event_time
    AND s2.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days')
    AND s2.games_played > 0
  LEFT JOIN session_log as sl_1
    ON r.name = sl_1.name
    AND sl_1.event_time >= r.event_time
    AND sl_1.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days')
    AND sl_1.level_at_end > 0
  LEFT JOIN session_log as sl_2
    ON r.name = sl_2.name
    AND sl_2.event_time >= r.event_time
    AND sl_2.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days')
    AND sl_2.level_at_end > 1
  LEFT JOIN session_log as sl_3
    ON r.name = sl_3.name
    AND sl_3.event_time >= r.event_time
    AND sl_3.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days')
    AND sl_3.level_at_end > 2
  LEFT JOIN session_log as sl_4
    ON r.name = sl_4.name
    AND sl_4.event_time >= r.event_time
    AND sl_4.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days')
    AND sl_4.level_at_end > 3
  LEFT JOIN session_log as sl_5
    ON r.name = sl_5.name
    AND sl_5.event_time >= r.event_time
    AND sl_5.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days')
    AND sl_5.level_at_end > 4
  LEFT JOIN session_log as sl_10
    ON r.name = sl_10.name
    AND sl_10.event_time >= r.event_time
    AND sl_10.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days')
    AND sl_10.level_at_end > 9
WHERE r.event_time >= '2014-07-01'
      AND r.event_time < '2014-07-30'
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day DESC;
```

It works, but very slow. Is there a way to speed up this query?

Comment: Please, add a link to the http://explain.depesz.com/ that contains `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)` output of your slow query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my resulting query is the following:

```sql
SELECT
  date(reg_time)  AS day,
  count(glid)     AS registrations,
  sum(CASE WHEN games_played IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS logged_in,
  sum(CASE WHEN games_played > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS played_users,
  sum(CASE WHEN level_at_end > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lvl1,
  sum(CASE WHEN level_at_end > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lvl2,
  sum(CASE WHEN level_at_end > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lvl3,
  sum(CASE WHEN level_at_end > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lvl4,
  sum(CASE WHEN level_at_end > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lvl5,
  sum(CASE WHEN level_at_end > 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lvl10
FROM (SELECT
        max(r.event_time)   AS reg_time,
        r.glid,
        max(s.level_at_end) AS level_at_end,
        sum(s.games_played) AS games_played
      FROM registrations AS r
        LEFT JOIN session_log AS s
          ON r.glid = s.glid
             AND s.event_time >= r.event_time
             AND s.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 day')
      GROUP BY r.glid
      ORDER BY reg_time DESC) AS foo
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day DESC;
```

The key is nested `select` with aggrgation and `left join` it simple precalulates all needed values.

Answer (score -1):

How about to use CASE? F.e.:

```
SELECT
  date(r.event_time)      AS day,
  count(DISTINCT r.name)  AS registrations,
  count(distinct CASE WHEN s.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days') THEN s.name ELSE null END) AS logged_in,
  count(distinct CASE WHEN s.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days') AND s.games_played > 0) THEN s.name ELSE null END) AS played_users
  count(distinct CASE WHEN s.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days') AND s.level_at_end > 0) THEN s.name ELSE null END) AS lvl1
  count(distinct CASE WHEN s.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days') AND s.level_at_end > 1) THEN s.name ELSE null END) AS lvl2
  count(distinct CASE WHEN s.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days') AND s.level_at_end > 2) THEN s.name ELSE null END) AS lvl3
  count(distinct CASE WHEN s.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days') AND s.level_at_end > 3) THEN s.name ELSE null END) AS lvl4
  count(distinct CASE WHEN s.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days') AND s.level_at_end > 4) THEN s.name ELSE null END) AS lvl5
  count(distinct CASE WHEN s.event_time < date_trunc('day', r.event_time + INTERVAL '1 days') AND s.level_at_end > 5) THEN s.name ELSE null END) AS lvl10
FROM registrations AS r
LEFT JOIN session_log AS s
    ON r.name = s.name
       AND s.event_time >= r.event_time
WHERE r.event_time >= '2014-07-01'
      AND r.event_time < '2014-07-30'
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day DESC;
```

Comment: I can count logged_in and played_users only from session_log table. In you example there is only registrations table is used. so, it won't work.

Comment: Then join session_log once and use "CASE" for aggregations.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: How would you integrate levels in you query? I think you cannot solve levels counting with CASE because one user can have many entries in session log, but I need to count only max level for each user.

Comment: Edited, I think it should return the same result

Comment: No, it wont, because session_log might have several records for each player... In your query each record will be counted, so results will be higher that actual values. I did check it locally and it doesn't work.